# jquery, save entire DOM for reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, dom

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){

        var xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><foo><bar>bar</bar></foo>';

        document.open("text/xml", "replace");
        document.write(xml);

        document.execCommand('SaveAs',true,'file.xml');

    });

</script>

 </head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This html-file generates an xml file (in IE) and creates a "save as" dialog. However, I would like to reset the document to its previous state (before the "replace") after I have saved the file. Is this possible using pure javascript or jQuery? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run that code against the `document` from an `<iframe>` instead of replacing the current document.

Comment: Thanks, followup questions: Are there any jquery versions of `document.open`? I suppose `document.write` can be replaced by `append()`. I would like to set the encoding of the xml, if thats possible.

Comment: No.  `document.write` has nothing to do with `append`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save the entire dom. Just save the values of what can change (form fields and other small UI bits that are communicative) and update those when necessary.

If necessary, write a reset function that you can call whenever you need it.

Comment: I think i may have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

simply no because document.open() clears the document.
you should do what SLaks says.

read it https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.open

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do it all in a popup window?

$(function(){
        var popup = window.open()
        var xml = 'bar';

```
    popup.document.open("text/xml", "replace");
    popup.document.write(xml);

    popup.document.execCommand('SaveAs',true,'file.xml');
    popup.close();
});
```